# Webservice NF Paulistana não retorna C#

Tags: c#, web-service, nfe

Caros, Boa Tarde. Estou com alguns problemas com o uso do webservice da nota fiscal paulistana, onde preciso buscar as Notas Fiscais Recebidas e me trazer essas informações. Eu já crio o arquivo XML para enviar na chamada da função, porém não está retornando o que eu preciso, sempre retorna algo como "Server Internal Error". Aparentemente a formatação do arquivo está correta, mas pela mensagem não é o que parece. Abaixo o resultado final do meu XML, verifiquem se está correto.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p1:PedidoConsultaNFePeriodo xmlns:p1="http://www.prefeitura.sp.gov.br/nfe" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Cabecalho Versao="1">
        <CPFCNPJRemetente>
            <CNPJ>00000000000000</CNPJ>
        </CPFCNPJRemetente>
        <CPFCNPJ>
            <CNPJ>00000000000000</CNPJ>
        </CPFCNPJ>
        <Inscricao>00000000</Inscricao>
        <dtInicio>2015-11-01</dtInicio>
        <dtFim>2015-11-30</dtFim>
        <NumeroPagina>1</NumeroPagina>
    </Cabecalho>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
        <SignedInfo>
            <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
            <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
            <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <DigestValue>9HSKC2wOPMBRcXxM0qqwFUwkveg=</DigestValue>
            </Reference>
        </SignedInfo>
        <SignatureValue>BWEW67Qau/ksFMPstUf5cHBw087/Zs0CPsp1lqTSJCkWlh6HWuXj1yoWnFR/GCiV5/PnzlCFeCRr5yNUEcEMLyjxuYr8HaZ3W0DOOwclCThMvGFUfUtESoSBfhmirai6qPVn9fIlE7jaTnpl4imO0ZIonrCeEJqS9vXjzWZ/c+IknvT4Q8jvYq9y5lJb+vDZzIsr2HHk4HFZYaJFvGHlPeUTVvu8Lf4qveVwIwOdxYqOOSJBXpuj7kS1wuZLKifOORpx4vrazG+Xnl3/fpbZrW5DZGCYDCKY9uGwu8Wy2nhdbpxZMhWmKAf1fHRL8l+yksBN16BUx7yEVZ7G7kUPFg==</SignatureValue>
        <KeyInfo>
            <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>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</X509Certificate>
            </X509Data>
        </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
</p1:PedidoConsultaNFePeriodo>
```

Para enviar realizar o POST, uso o esquema de HTTP, então não sei se é preciso alterar algo por ali também.

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O erro que você está indicando é muito amplo e indica problema no servidor. Você já fez contato com a instituição que você envia para te darem uma posição do que pode estar ocorrendo? O erro ocorre exatamente no método que você faz a requisição enviando o seu arquivo?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver? Provavelmente é o valor da assinatura e o valor do <CPFCNPJRemetente>. Qual o SOAPAction?